# How can I download CiviCRM tar file with Drush?

Tags: drupal, drush

Is there a way I can automatize this download in order to use `drush civicrm-install`

I'm trying to automatize deployment of CiviCRM in Drupal 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathieu a.k.a @bgm (who runs much of the CiviCRM project's infrastructure) wrote this:

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=30003.msg128559#msg128559

To summarize: [I checked the link to that example makefile - still works]!

```
I deploy with "Drush make":

* deploy from my git repos or from the civicrm standard ones (drush make example.make)
* run GenCode.php

Example makefile: https://gist.github.com/mlutfy/5310366
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to install it in the Drush way but I get an error: `Tarfile unpacked [OK] CiviCRM installer helper file is missing. [ERROR]`. The strange thing is that this a fresh install of Drupal, but I can't find anything on the web about it so the problem has to be in my end

Comment: It was indeed in my end, I was introducing the tar parameter ending in tar.gz which was not correct. But the installer did not complain! I will make a bug report

Comment: Ah - glad you worked through it! Perhaps next time try drush make?